# Preventing <script> tags in html form input

Tags: javascript, html, forms, security, xss

I developed a website, which can be accessed at https://ublostandfound.000webhostapp.com. Some user is trying to get my website to redirect to other websites by using  tags in the HTML form input. I'm not entirely sure how he is doing this, but is there some way I can prevent users from entering  tags in the form in the first place?

Answer (score -1):

The best practice is the sanitize user input on the server, but in a server less environment anyone can simply bypass this.

Either way you can sanitize (simply means make the data not runnable through script) by calling this function

```
 function sanitize(s) {
       return s.replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/"/g, '&quot;');
   }
```

Comment: It’s important to describe how to use this function.

Comment: @Ryan Yes I just realized I'm still lost lol

Comment: @SanchitBatra: Read the duplicate link at the top of the page: PHP has a built-in `htmlspecialchars` function (assuming you’re using PHP), and you should use it whenever you produce output.

Comment: I tried doing $input = htmlspecialchars($input); and using that, but it does not seem to be working. Am I doing this wrong?

Comment: @SanchitBatra: You don’t do it on your input; you do it when you’re producing output. For example, if you stored a user’s name in your database and put it in `$name`, instead of doing `<?= $name ?>` you would do `<?= htmlspecialchars($name) ?>` to make `$name` safe to put in HTML.

Comment: I got what I was doing wrong, it was really silly 

Comment: I took the form data and stored it in the variable $description AFTER I used the htmlspecialchars() method

Answer (score -1):

Before you store the input from the form, check for HTML tokens in each field and strip them out or reject the post. (look for < followed by > )

Comment: `<` doesn’t have to be followed by `>` to be dangerous, and the right place to do replacements is on output, not input.

Comment: I disagree Ryan, you need to prevent the invalid data from getting into your system. Once it gets past that single point of entry, you are storing invalid and dangerous data. Even if you guard against it in the places you believe are its only way out, as time goes by, it can migrate and find a new way into the wild. Stop it on the server and sleep easier.

Comment: *Validating* your data is a good idea, but that doesn’t exempt you from *escaping* it (i.e. performing replacements) on output. Valid input can be indistinguishable from an exploit, too: my last name contains an apostrophe, and your SQL had better be able to insert it properly.

Answer (score -2):

Escape your HTML entities, so that `<` becomes `&lt;`, etc. Make sure you do this on the server and not on the client, or a malicious client can bypass it.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand, which entities do I modify?

Comment: @SanchitBatra *all* of them. If you're using PHP, use `htmlentities()` when displaying any user-provided input.

Comment: This is missing a list of entities and how to do it.